# How to create navigation animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create an animation using jQuery which allows for a bubble to appear on the hover event as the user hovers over the list items identified by the id 'navigation'.  I have created a div identified by the id 'navigation_blob' which I would like to appear upon each item which is being hovered on.  For some reason, however, the height stays at 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('<div id="navigation_blob"></div>').css({
    width: 0,
    height: $('#navigation li:first a').height() + 10
  }).appendTo('#navigation');

  $('#navigation a').hover(
    function() { // Mouse over function
      $('#navigation_blob').animate({
        width: $(this).width() + 10,
        left: $(this).position().left
      }, {
        duration: 'slow',
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        queue: false
      });
    },
    function() { // Mouse out function
      $('#navigation_blob').animate({
        width: $(this).width() + 10,
        left: $(this).position().left
      }, {
        duration: 'slow',
        easing: 'easeOutCirc',
        queue: false
      });
    }
  );
});
```

```css
#head {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#navigation {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* overwrite base */
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation a {
  color: #015287;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation_blob {
  top: 0;
  background-color: #c0ffee;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

p#intro {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="key-technical-skillsets">
  <h5>Key Technical Skill Sets</h5>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MySQL<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Adobe Photoshop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

Comment: FYI: there is a typo at here: `MySQL<a/>` closing slash shold be before the letter `a`

Comment: You better provide the jsfiddle..

Comment: looks fine to me... https://jsfiddle.net/my5aad9d/  :).. ** just that jquery UI was missing which I had to add for easing effect **.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to make it work. see here : **[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv2of7kx/)**

you have to include `jquery-ui` in your project for the extended easing options.

add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>` in `<head>` section ( along with the jQuery library )

also.  `<li><a href="#">MySQL<a/></li>` is not correct, change it to `<li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>`

let me know if it works. cheers

EDIT AFTER COMMENT

if you want your list to be vertical, and the `li` to have `width:auto` ( the with of the text inside it ) set `li{display:list-item}`

and then, for the effect to move vertically instead of horizontally ( as it was in previous fiddle ) , change in JQ `left` to `top` .

here > `left: $(this).position().left` to `top: $(this).position().top` ( this code appears in 2 places )

PS. you have set in your HTML an `ol` = ordered list not an `ul` . if you change it to `ul` change also in CSS `ul` instead of `ol`

see here **[Verical Blob Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv2of7kx/2/)**

Comment: Thank you. I just reviewed the Jsfiddle and realised that I miscommunicated something. The navigation list IS NOT inline but a vertical list.  After reviewing your code I see that you have successfully got me to the point where it works but only if the list type is inline, otherwise the 'blob' does not move vertically upon hovering the mouse.  Can we fix this? Soryy I am new to this.. :(